# iPhone Application Deploy without using iTunes

Tags: iphone

I want to build an application for the iPhone to be used inside a customer enterprise (very small, only 5 to 10 devices). But since they will be paying the application development, I don't want to distribute that application to the world inside the App Store in iTunes. How can I distribute this app to my customer? Should I get the Enterprise level subscription from the Apple Developer Program? Since I work as a freelancer, I think I can't subscribe to that program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the client purchase the Enterprise subscription.

The alternative, since there are only a few devices, is to regularly provide provisioning profiles for all devices.  This sounds like a huge hassle to me.  The profiles expire every 3 months last I checked, but it has changed before.

If you really want to scrape the barrel, there is also jailbreaking :)

Comment: Or switch to Android on open devices

Comment: I was thinking debug profiles which only last 3 months.  A yearly update wouldn't be that bad if you are on a budget.  Especially if you are occasionally enhancing the software.